# Doctrine2 cannot save with EntityManager()->persist

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine-orm

I am using doctrine2 in symfony 2 frame work. I am getting problem in inserting new values.My sample code is given below

```
$order = new Order(); 
$order->setUser($user); // $user is object from user table 
$order->setAmount($d['amount']); 
$order->setStatus($this->getStatusAsInteger($orderStatus));
$this->getEntityManager()->persist($order); 
$this->getEntityManager()->flush();
```

The code returns no error.Any one please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Can you post your `Order` entity? Is `$user` persisted already? I find it hard to believe this wouldn't issue any errors in development mode

Comment: I can see Insert query in log which generated from doctrine , but it is not saving the entity

Comment: How do you know it's not saving the entity?

Comment: This is the log which I am getting. But it is not storing to database.
INSERT INTO orders (user_id, amount,status, created_at ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ? ) ({"1":2,"2":10000,"3":"1","4":{"date":"2011-11-15 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Tokyo"}) [] []

Comment: How do you know "it's not storing to database"?

Comment: I checked databse. I cannot find corresponding row in table.

Comment: Strange. If the request is logged, I hardly think it has failed. If other errors/exceptions always display fine, then I'd try doing step-by-step debugging with XDebug to see what really happens after that call to flush, and I'd triple check the database name.